# Matlab use a workspace variable within a function

Tags: matlab, function, variables, workspace

For some reason I need to use workspace variables within a function. How can I "import" these variables into my function? Thanks

Comment: Share your code. Are you asking how to pass values as arguments to a function?

Comment: Please read ["Function Basics"](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-basics.html) in the MATLAB documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Either pass the variables by argument or (and only seldom recommended) use global variables

Answer (score 1):

You can use `evalin('caller', ...)` or `evalin('base', ...)` to do this, but it is vastly preferable to pass arguments in explicitly.